# Mixing properties of multiple records in one .tfrecords file

Tags: tensorflow

I have a dataset of around 1M examples. I each example to a separate .tfrecord file, which resulted in around 500GB sitting in some network location.

Reading multiple small files from this network location is extremely slow, so I'm thinking about grouping around 100 examples into one .tfrecord file.

I am worried though, that examples from the same .tfrecords file will always appear in the same minibatch (or one minibatch after each other), which is bad for the proper mixing of training data I want to have.

my input pipeline is the following:
I have a `tf.train.string_input_producer(files, capacity=100000)` for the filenames queue, using `TFRecordReader.read` to read from the filenames queue, and use `tf.train.batch` that creates an examples queue and returns a batch from it using `dequeue_many`.

I fear that once the filenames queue dequeues a filename, all examples from it will be read and enqueued into the examples FIFO queue created by `tf.train.batch`, which will result in the same examples being in the same minibatches over and over.

Is it really going to have the same examples in the same minibatch over and over? If so, should I create a Shuffle queue for examples, instead of using `tf.train.batch`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the points of TFRecord is to store many files in the same location to overcome the problem of opening/closing many files. So your approach of one tfrecord per one example does not make sense. You can put even all examples in one file or have 10k per file. Regarding shuffling: there are two types shuffling which serve different purposes and shuffle different things:

- [`tf.train.string_input_producer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer) *shuffle: Boolean. If true, the strings are randomly shuffled within each epoch.*. So if you have a few files `['file1', 'file2', ..., 'filen']` this randomly selects a file from this list. If case of false, the files follow one after each other.
- [`tf.train.shuffle_batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch) *Creates batches by randomly shuffling tensors.* So it takes `batch_size` tensors from your queue (you will need to create a queue with `tf.train.start_queue_runners` ) and shuffles them.

Comment: I think it is important to mention the min_after_dequeue parameter of tf.train.shuffle_batch(), when working with files that contain many examples. As long as min_after_dequeue is large enough, a good mix of values can be guaranteed. But on the other hand, let's say when each tf.record file contains 100 examples, and the min_after_dequeue=~100, then you can expect all examples in a batch coming from the same file.